# JOIN read performance without foreign keys vs join with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, performance, join, foreign-keys, crud

I've been reading many related posts but there doesn't seem to be a definitive answer on the topic.
DB - mysql
Tables - employee, department
No foreign keys, but employee does have department_id column and that column **IS** indexed 
Is there a performance advantage to adding a foreign key constraint on the employee.department_id column ? Will the joins (for selects) be faster when both tables have millions of records or will they be about the same if I index employee.department_id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foreign key constraints are used for integrity, to ensure that one column's values are a subset of another's. Provided that your columns are indexed either way, FK constraints will make no difference to read performance. They will, however, affect insert/update/delete performance.

Comment: How FK affect insert, update, and delete? Will slow down execution?

Comment: @Čamo An FK constraint can slow down an insert or update query to check that the constrained column's value exists in the referenced column. An update or delete query can be delayed by cascading updates. However, these checks/updates are usually quick and it's generally quicker to do them as part of the transaction that needs them, rather than expect an app to do such checks/updates manually. Ensuring integrity also maintains performance due to correct and expected operating conditions, whereas broken integrity leads to a variety of problems that can affect performance negatively.